# Cocoa-Touch: dynamically resizing views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a `UITableView` which occupies the entire screen, besides a navigation bar.
The `UINavigationItem` has a `UIBarButtonItem` that shows a previously hidden `UIPickerView` when tapped.

I'm trying to resize the `UITableView` so that it occupies the rest of the screen not used by the now visible `UIPickerView`.

I know the framework already does something like this, when focusing a text field, it resizes the entire app's view and pops up the keyboard at the bottom.

What's the best way to do this?
I'd just like to make sure I'm not doing it wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the dimensions of a view by changing that view's `frame` property.  The frame consists of two structs: a point indicating the origin (TL corner) of the view, and a size indicating its width and height.  Simply create a new CGRect, assign it to your view's `frame` property, and you'll have dynamically resized your view.

Comment: So there is definetely no layouting offered by the framework?

Comment: In the sense of layout managers that you find in other GUI frameworks, not really.  There are the springs and struts that you can set in Interface Builder, but they're not true "Layout" managers.